# Using cross-entropy loss in denoising autoencoder saturates output

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am using this [implementation](https://gist.github.com/blackecho/3a6e4d512d3aa8aa6cf9) of a denoising autoencoder on the CIFAR10 dataset which has been scaled to [0,1]. 
My hyperparameters are -

```
Adam optimizer 
lr = 0.0001
sigmoid activations for both encoder and decoder
512 hidden nodes
Batch size = 50
```

On setting the loss function to be cross entropy, it starts out pretty huge on first training step. But then it converges to 0 within 3 steps which made me suspicious. After training for a bit, I passed an image into the AE and on evaluating the output of the decode layer, they were all 1's or close to it instead of the original image values.

I have a slight understanding of what is going on. The cross-entropy loss is defined in the code as -

`tf.reduce_sum(self.input_data * tf.log(self.decode))`

If the decode layer has values of all 1's then `tf.log(self.decode)` is close to zero. So the network optimizes its hidden weights such that the output is close to 1 so that cross-entropy is equal to zero. Am I correct?

How do I work around this?

Comment: What activation function are you using in the hidden layers?

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** cross entropy loss. For a bernoulli output variable (and since you are using sigmoids this means they are bernoullis) it should be

```
-tf.reduce_sum(
  self.input_data * tf.log(self.decode) + 
  (1-self.input_data)*(tf.log(1-self.decode)))
```

Comment: Output isn't binary, it's in the range [0,1]

Comment: @HMK the same applies to bernoullis

Comment: So when do we use only the first term of the cross entropy loss versus the entire function? I know the former is used in case of multi-class classification but I'm not sure about other cases.

Comment: we never use "only the first term" it is always **sum over all classes** (over all possible values of dependant variable). And in a special case when there are just 2 classes (bernoulli y) we have p(y=1|x) = 1 - p(y=0|x), thus what you call "the second term" is just a first term applied to second probability.

Comment: What would be the reduction_indices/axis parameter for tf.reduce_sum be in this case?

Comment: both, and similarly reduce_mean could be used too